# classifying integer data by tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to classify 
if input data is under 200 than output is (0, 1)
and if input data is over 200 than output is (1, 0)

input value is sequential integer value and layer is 5.

hidden layer use sigmoid and last hidden layer use softmax function

loss function is reduce_mean and training with gradient descendent

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def set_x_data():
    x_data = np.array([[50]
                     , [60]
                     , [70]
                     , [80]
                     , [90]
                     , [110]
                     , [120]
                     , [130]
                     , [140]
                     , [150]
                     , [160]
                     , [170]
                     , [180]
                     , [190]
                     , [200]
                     , [210]
                     , [220]
                     , [230]
                     , [240]
                     , [250]
                     , [260]
                     , [270]
                     , [280]
                     , [290]
                     , [300]
                     , [310]
                     , [320]
                     , [330]
                     , [340]
                     , [350]
                     , [360]
                     , [370]
                     , [380]
                     , [390]])

    return x_data

def set_y_data(x):
    y_data = np.array([[0, 1]
                     , [0, 1]
                     , [0, 1]
                     , [0, 1]
                     , [0, 1]
                     , [0, 1]
                     , [0, 1]
                     , [0, 1]
                     , [0, 1]
                     , [0, 1]
                     , [0, 1]
                     , [0, 1]
                     , [0, 1]
                     , [0, 1]
                     , [0, 1]
                     , [0, 1]
                     , [1, 0]
                     , [1, 0]
                     , [1, 0]
                     , [1, 0]
                     , [1, 0]
                     , [1, 0]
                     , [1, 0]
                     , [1, 0]
                     , [1, 0]
                     , [1, 0]
                     , [1, 0]
                     , [1, 0]
                     , [1, 0]
                     , [1, 0]
                     , [1, 0]
                     , [1, 0]
                     , [1, 0]
                     , [1, 0]])
    return y_data

def set_bias(efficiency):
    arr = np.array([efficiency])

    return arr

W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, 5]), name='weight1')
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5]), name='weight2')
W3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5]), name='weight3')
W4 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5]), name='weight4')
W5 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 2]), name='weight5')

def inference(input, b):
    hidden_layer1 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(input, W1) + b)
    hidden_layer2 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(hidden_layer1, W2) + b)
    hidden_layer3 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(hidden_layer2, W3) + b)
    hidden_layer4 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(hidden_layer3, W4) + b)
    out_layer = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(hidden_layer4, W5) + b)

    return out_layer

def loss(hypothesis, y):
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(hypothesis), reduction_indices=[1]))

    return cross_entropy

def train(loss):
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)
    train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

    return train

x_data = set_x_data(1)
y_data = set_y_data(0)
b_data = set_bias(0.8)

x= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])
y= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None])

hypothesis = inference(x, b)
loss = loss(hypothesis, y)
train = train(loss)

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

print(sess.run(W1))

for step in range(2000):
    sess.run(train, feed_dict={x:x_data, y:y_data, b:b_data})

print(sess.run(W1))
print(sess.run(hypothesis, feed_dict={x:np.array([[1000]]), b:b_data}))
```

when I print W1 before training and after training, value doesn't change specially and testing when input = 1000, that value doesn't currect what I expect. I think value nearly close to (1, 0), but result is almost (0.5, 0.5)

I guess that mistakes come from loss function because it was copied from here and there, but I can't be sure about it

---

upper code is just simplified of my code but I think I have to show my real code

the code is too long so I create new post

[classifying data by tensorflow but accuracy value didn't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53790116/classifying-data-by-tensorflow-but-accuracy-value-didnt-change)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in the training of the above network, but with a few changes you can achieve a network that gets [this decision function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caLCi.png)

([The plot in the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caLCi.png) shows the score of class 2, i.e. if x > 200)

The list of issues subject to improvement in this network:

- **The training data is very scarce** (only 34 points!) This is typically too small, especially for a 5-layer network as in your case. You typically want many more input samples than parameters in the network. Try adding more input values and reducing the number of layers (as in the code below - I've used floats instead of integers to get more points, but I think it is still compatible).
- **The input ranges typically require scaling** (below I've tried a super-simple scaling by dividing by a constant). This is because you typically want to avoid high ranges of variables (especially of you pass many layers with a soft-max non-linearity, this would destroy the information contained in the very high or very low values). In more advanced cases you might want to do Min-Max Scaling or z-scores.
- **Try more epochs** (and try plotting the evolution of the loss function value). With the given number of epochs, the optimization of the loss function had not converged. Below I do 10x more epochs. See how the code below now almost converges in [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OhZg.png) (and see how 2000 epochs were not enough):
- Something that helped was **shuffling the (x,y) data**. Though this is not crucial in this case, it converges faster (see the paper "[Efficient Backprop](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf)" by Le Cun). And in more serious examples it is typically needed.
- Importantly, **I think you want `b` to be a parameter**, not a constant, don't you? The bias of a network is typically also optimized together with the multiplicative weights. (Also, it is not common to use a single, shared bias for all the hidden layers. )

Below is the code. Note there might be further improvements but these few tricks end up with the desired decision function.

I've added some inline comments to indicate changes with respect to the original. I hope you find these pieces of advice insightful!

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# I've modified the functions set_x_data and set_y_data
# so as to generate a larger set of numbers. 

# Generate a range of numbers from 50 to 390
def set_x_data():
    x_data = np.arange(50, 390, 0.1)
    return x_data[:,None]

# Assign labels depending on x_data
def set_y_data(x_data):
    ydata1 = x_data >= 200
    ydata2 = x_data < 200
    return np.hstack((ydata1, ydata2))

def set_bias(efficiency):
    arr = np.array([efficiency])

    return arr

# Let's keep W1 and W5 (one hidden layer only)
# BTW, in this problem you could do with 0 hidden layers. But keeping
# 1 to show it works
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, 5]), name='weight1')
W5 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 2]), name='weight5')

# BTW, b should be a parameter, too. 
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0))

# Just keeping 1 hidden layer
def inference(input):
    hidden_layer1 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(input, W1) + b)
    out_layer = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(hidden_layer1, W5) + b)

    return out_layer

# This is unchanged
def loss(hypothesis, y):
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(hypothesis), reduction_indices=[1]))

    return cross_entropy

# This is unchanged
def train(loss):
    optimizer = 
tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)
    train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

    return train

# Using SCALE to normalize the input variables (range of inputs too big)
# This is a simple normalization in this case. Other examples are 
# Min-Max normalization or z-scores. 

SCALE = 1000
x_data = set_x_data()
y_data = set_y_data(x_data)
x_data /= SCALE

# Now only placeholders are x and y (b is a parameter)
x= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])
y= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])

hypothesis = inference(x)
loss = loss(hypothesis, y)
train = train(loss)

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

print(sess.run(W1))

# Epochs x 10, it did not converge with fewer epochs
epochs = 20000
losses = np.zeros(epochs)
for step in range(epochs):
# Shuffle data
    r = np.random.permutation(x_data.shape[0])
    x_data = x_data[r]
    y_data = y_data[r,:]
    # Small modification here to capture the loss. 
    _, l = sess.run([train, loss], feed_dict={x:x_data, y:y_data})
    losses[step] = l

print(sess.run(W1))
print(sess.run(b))
```

The code to display the decision function above:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ystar = np.arange(50, 400, 10)[:,None]
plt.plot(ystar, sess.run(hypothesis, feed_dict={x:ystar/SCALE})[:,0])
```

Comment: I'm really appreciate with your help. I was just expect that only clue of my code but you give in a hole code to try it.

so I want to do myself based on your code and I was try some ways based on your code but I can't find a way to solve this.

when I try that code, loss is decrease but accuracy didn't change ever.

can you give me some advise to me just a little?

I just only expect of a little clue.
I'm sorry that code is too long.

and I'm really appreciate your help before. Thanks.